# React-native build failed

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I am experiencing the following difficulty with the react native application. If someone can help with a solution it's appreciated.

JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.so' for Linux i386.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
  Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
  set up your Android development environment:
  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: can you help this?  `cd android && gradlew clean`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have tried to delete `android/app/build` folder and `node_modules` folder.

after removing them , in your root folder of project run following commands in terminal

```
npm install --save

react-native link

react-native run-android
```

After still does not work run following commands after running above commands

```
adb devices 

adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

if web server is not running

```
react-native start
```

Comment: Yeah as you said I removed the node modules as well. After running the react-native link command I got the following. That's good.
"rnpm-install info Linking assets to ios project ,
rnpm-install info Linking assets to android project 
rnpm-install info Assets have been successfully linked to your project "
 But the issue is still the same.

Comment: second adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

Comment: than start web server react-native start

Comment: shake phone to reload app

Comment: Not sure how to do that.

Comment: @RuchiraChamara here is link to learn more https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks. I think I have done that. Many thanks for the good guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#docsNav).I think you are trying to run this command before setting up the signing configuration.

Comment: Hi Naleen,
Thanks for the comment. I haven't done those steps which you have refereed to me. Do we need to do those as well when we are just trying to run the application with react-native. Because earlier time I didn't do those as I can remember.

Comment: if you want to install app in device as production so you should complete this step before build.

Comment: Ah OK got it. But I was trying to run the application in my phone.

Comment: Do you have a problem with running in device in debug mode?